# Can I grab specific page HTML code from another webpage through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I've read about how there are multiple methods to grabbing source code from another webpage via jQuery or using Cross-Domain Requests. What I want to try and do is make it so I grab a div that has different code each time a page is loaded and not the source code as a whole. So for example, the greater detail you see when you use 'inspect element' or a tool like firebug to dive deeper into the page code.

Would I be using one of the same methods?

Comment: No, because all said methods can obtain is the source code. You then have to parse/manipulate the source code to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Would need to use headless browser on your server to get fully rendered page

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you control BOTH domains you can add the `Access_control_CORS`
header to allow access of cross domain requests and use a 
headless browser like phantomJS to grab a cached version of 
rendered `HTML` page.

If you don't control both domains you will have to write a server
side proxy to grab the page and all its resources (you will have 
to parse the page to get or rewrite links to images, javascripts,
stylesheets etc...) then run it through `phantomJS` to create a 
`HTML` snapshot.`

source:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
http://phantomjs.org/
```

NOTE: despite my best efforts, stack overflow is absolutely convinced these links are code. Sorry for posting as code.

Comment: That's fine. Thank you for the input still. We do control both domains. I'm using the CORS headers and right now one of the issues I'm having is that for whatever reason, the div id is not being grabbed but that's a whole separate syntax issue I need to figure out.

Comment: is that div being created by javascript?